# funcion boolean devuelve integer o no reconoce

Tags: java

Tengo esta función boolean:

```
    public boolean remove(T elem){
    boolean ezabatu = false;
    if (this.first.equals(elem)){
        this.removeFirst();
        ezabatu = true;
    }else{
        while (this.actual.next!=null && !ezabatu){
            if(this.actual.next.equals(elem)){
                this.remove();
                ezabatu = true;
            }
            this.actual = this.actual.next;
        }
    }
    this.actual = this.first;
    return ezabatu;
}
```

y lo utilizo aquí:

```
int elem = teklatu.nextInt();
    if(osokoLista.remove(elem)){
        System.out.println(...);
    }else{
        System.out.println(...);
}
```

en el if me salta el error "cannot convert from Integer to boolean" y no entiendo el porqué

Comment: En Java no hay funciones, sino métodos, atados a una clase. A qué clase corresponde tu método `remove` ? Y de qué clase es el objeto `teklatu`?

Comment: No es posible ayudar sin el código completo.el error aparece en  if pero puede ser hasta su método `this.removeFirst();`